# Virtuoso with DbPedia on Amazon: Connection refused

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtuoso

I have tried to install a Virtuoso machine with DBpedia data to run a DBpedia endpoint on my own server. I have followed everything in this [guide](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtAWSDBpedia38).

Though, every time I try to access the endpoint using URL `http://ec2-ami-public-dns-cname/resource/Bob_Marley` or simply `http://ec2-ami-public-dns-cname/`, I get `CONNECTION_REFUSED` response.

I tried to do that using `wget` inside the machine and I still got the same response.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide misses an important step

Based on this [guide](http://planet.lod2.eu/post/112443584/Virtuoso-DBpedia-3-6-Installation-Guide-Update), you still need to configure the clusters by running

```
[root@your_machine]# . /opt/virtuoso/bin/virtuoso-mkclusters.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

That instance-backed AMI was originally built in 2008 and last substantially updated in 2012, based on Virtuoso 6, and populated with DBpedia 3.8. The guide you linked needed a number of related updates, which are in progress.

I think you will likely be much happier today with the [current, EBS-backed, Pay-as-you-go AMI, based on Virtuoso 7, and populated with DBpedia 2015 a/k/a DBpedia 3.10](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtPayAsYouGoEBSBackedAMIDBpedia2015).

Also... for future reference, assistance with [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) and other products from [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/) (my employer) is often delivered more quickly and accurately through the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), our [public Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), and [confidential support cases](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp)